# Max recursion in "pip install" & "setup.py install"

Tags: python, python-install

I'm trying to install a package (splinter) on a Macbook (OS X 10.6.8), but I keep getting maximum recursion errors.  They occur whether I use "setup.py install" or "pip install", and whether I try to do a global install or use virtualenv.  They occurred both under Python 2.7.1 and 2.7.2.  They occur when I do it a boat, they occur when I do it with a goat.

Please note that no one else seems to be having this problem with the splinter package.

The loopy bit of my trace back:

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 177, in run
    self.find_sources()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 252, in find_sources
    mm.run()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 306, in run
    self.add_defaults()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 330, in add_defaults
    sdist.add_defaults(self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/sdist.py", line 264, in add_defaults
    for pkg, src_dir, build_dir, filenames in build_py.data_files:
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/command/build_py.py", line 39, in __getattr__
    self.data_files = files = self._get_data_files(); return files
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/command/build_py.py", line 44, in _get_data_files
    self.analyze_manifest()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/command/build_py.py", line 92, in analyze_manifest
    self.run_command('egg_info')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
```

My Python path:

```
/Users/gimli/Work/LocalSystemGimli/troubleshooting/splinter_install
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.0-py2.7.egg
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.6.4-py2.7.egg
/Users/gimli/Work/LocalSystemGimli/troubleshooting/splinter_install
/opt/local/www
/opt/local/www/swage_block/libraries/django_tastypie
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/lxml-2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/python_dateutil-1.5-py2.6.egg
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/python_digest-1.7-py2.6.egg
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/simplejson-2.1.6-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mimeparse-0.1.3-py2.6.egg-info
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python
```

The pip.log has many, many, many warnings that "warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found".

`setuptools.__version__` is 0.6c9, `setuptools.distutils.__version__` is 2.7.2.

Strangely, the `__file__` for the setuptools module is under the 2.6 installation directory, but that for setuptools.disutils is under the 2.7 installation.

I suspect the problem is some subtle error in my installation of 2.7 or some dependent module (the computer came with 2.6 installed) but I can't for the life of me figure the problem.

Comment: +1 for "They occur when I do it on a boat, they occur when I do it with a goat."  However, you need to edit the question so your joke reads correctly (=

Comment: +1 same problem was driving me nuts. thanks for posting this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install a separate version of either `Distribute` or `setuptools` (the two sources for the `easy_install` command) for your Python 2.7 installation.  Each Python instance must have its own.  The Apple-supplied system Pythons in 10.6 come with their own `easy_install` in `/usr/bin` and `setuptools` in their Apple-supplied packages.  The Python 2.7 you installed does not automatically come with one.  Notice in the traceback how you start with Python 2.7 and then pick up `setuptools` from 2.6.  Do not mix Python versions on a PYTHONPATH!

Comment: +1 THANK YOU this has been driving me nuts.  The fresh install of setuptools solved the problem.  Perhaps it would be helpful if there were an << assert >> in setuptools to check version correspondence among the setuptools module and Python?

Comment: "Do not mix Python versions on a PYTHONPATH!"  does this mean that a python upgrade should be followed by a reinstallation of everything in site-packages?

Comment: If you are switching "major" versions, say, from Python 2.6 to 2.7, yes.

Comment: Caramba!  The documentation on python upgrade is less than emphatic on that point.  Perhaps I missed the crucial admonition.